# Initialize List to a variable in a Dictionary inside a loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been working for a while in Python and I have solved this issue using "try" and "except", but I was wondering if there is another method to solve it.

Basically I want to create a dictionary like this:

```
example_dictionary = {"red":[2,3,4],"blue":[6,7,8],"orange":[10,11,12]}
```

So if I have a variable with the following content:

```
root_values = [{"name":"red","value":2},{"name":"red","value":3},{"name":"red","value":4},{"blue":6}...]
```

My way to implement the example_dictionary was:

```
example_dictionary = {}
for item in root_values:
   try:
       example_dictionary[item.name].append(item.value)
   except:
       example_dictionary[item.name] =[item.value]
```

I hope my question is clear and someone can help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Your code is not appending elements to the lists; you are instead replacing the list with single elements. To access values in your existing dictionaries, you must use indexing, not attribute lookups (`item['name']`, not `item.name`).

Use [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

example_dictionary = defaultdict(list)
for item in root_values:
    example_dictionary[item['name']].append(item['value'])
```

`defaultdict` is a `dict` subclass that uses the [`__missing__` hook on `dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) to auto-materialize values if the key doesn't yet exist in the mapping.

or use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
example_dictionary = {}
for item in root_values:
    example_dictionary.setdefault(item['name'], []).append(item['value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

List and dictionary comprehensions can help here ...

Given

```
In [72]: root_values
Out[72]:
[{'name': 'red', 'value': 2},
 {'name': 'red', 'value': 3},
 {'name': 'red', 'value': 2},
 {'name': 'green', 'value': 7},
 {'name': 'green', 'value': 8},
 {'name': 'green', 'value': 9},
 {'name': 'blue', 'value': 4},
 {'name': 'blue', 'value': 4},
 {'name': 'blue', 'value': 4}]
```

A function like `item()` shown below can extract values with specific names:

```
In [75]: def item(x): return [m['value'] for m in root_values if m['name']==x]
In [76]: item('red')
Out[76]: [2, 3, 2]
```

Then, its just a matter of dictionary comprehension ...

```
In [77]: {x:item(x) for x in ['red', 'green', 'blue']  }
Out[77]: {'blue': [4, 4, 4], 'green': [7, 8, 9], 'red': [2, 3, 2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a way to do this without using collections.defaultdict() or dict.setdefault().

```py
>>> root_vals = [{"name":"red","value":2},{"name":"red","value":3},{"name":"red","value":4}]
>>> hashmap = {}
>>> for item in root_vals:
...     k, v = item["name"], item["value"]
...     hashmap[k] = hashmap.get(k, []) + [v]
... 
>>> hashmap
{'red': [2, 3, 4]}
```